# Assigning a reference to a string in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a string stored in a vector (`elements` in this case). I want to take a string at a particular index and store is in a variable called `x`. However, it doesn't seem to be working. The following results in a blank output:

```
string x = elements->at(index);
cout << x;
```

However, if I do something like:

```
cout << elements->at(index);
```

The string at index returns fine.

My elements is defined like so:

```
vector<string>* elements; 
elements = new vector<string>(size);
```

Am I missing something here? Is the problem in these lines or should I be looking elsewhere in the code?

Comment: How is `elements` defined? `vector<string> elements`?

Comment: [Should work](http://ideone.com/F4xIWw)

Comment: @Borgleader You forgot to share your `main.cpp`. :P

Comment: @herohuyongtao Nah, coliru seems to be broken atm. let me fix that.

Comment: My elements is defined like so:

    `vector<string>* elements;`
    `elements = new vector<string>(size);`

Comment: Not that it would fix your issue, but does `elements` really need to be dynamically allocated?

Comment: @Bob Please add such info to your question. Not in the comment.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Just took care of that. Thanks.

Comment: @Borgleader Yes. Can I achieve what I'm trying to do even if that is the case?

Comment: @Bob Definitely, I just mentioned it because as a general rule you should avoid dynamic allocation whenever possible. Would it possible for you to post a small compilable example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Absolutely. Let me put something together.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue http://ideone.com/xNdrNR.

Comment: @Bob How and when do you fill the vector `elements`?

Comment: This problem seems to only be present in my program which is very similar to a double ended queue implemented with a vector. I'm having a hard time figuring out why this would be, as well as putting together a code sample to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine when I try it:

http://ideone.com/sgOtc5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    std::vector<std::string> *elements;
    elements = new std::vector<std::string>(size);

    (*elements)[0] = "this";
    (*elements)[1] = "works";
    (*elements)[2] = "fine";

    std::string x = elements->at(1);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    std::cout << elements->at(1) << std::endl;

    x = (*elements)[1];
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    std::cout << (*elements)[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
works
works
works
works
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that the syntax is correct. All of the responses here seem to have pointed to some weird bug in my program.

Comment: Most likely, but you did not show the code that is filling or using the vector, so no one can tell you what that bug actually is.